# convert mongodb lookup aggregation to elasticsearch query

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

i have collection parent child in mongodb and i use this query like this

```
[{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'child',
        localField: 'parent_id',
        foreignField: 'parent_id',
        as: 'items'
    }
}, {
    $unionWith: {
        coll: 'child',
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                channel_id: 1
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        created_at: -1
    }
}]
```

our schema in elastic like mongo schema (parent, child) with same data.
how to convert that mongo query to elastic query with same result?